# JNI Issue on certain devices

Tags: android, java-native-interface

Hi everyone I have a problem on certain android devices (This device is running android 5.1)

I have the following code

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL
Java_com_peachss_sadldecoder_Decoder_getDecodedPhoto(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz,
                                                     jbyteArray photo_data, jint size) {

    jbyte* input= env->GetByteArrayElements(photo_data, 0);
    WiResultImage decode = DecodeImage((unsigned char*)input, size + 1);

    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(photo_data, input, JNI_ABORT);

    jbyteArray output  = env->NewByteArray(decode.size);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(output, 0, decode.size, (jbyte*)decode.raw);
    return output;
}
```

The moment it reaches 'NewByteArray' I get the following error

Signal: SIGABRT (signal SIGABRT)

Comment: You should probably include the entire stacktrace in your question (including any abort message that was output).

Comment: there is no stack trace, the app would instantly crash and then that is in the Console log

Comment: That sounds odd. Native crashes would usually result in a stacktrace.

Comment: Found this in the Logcat
2022-03-31 22:58:17.686 5502-5502/com.peachss.test A/libc: heap corruption detected by dlmalloc_real